# Passing Lamda function to Generic function not working

Tags: kotlin

I am playing with Kotlin and I am trying to convert a working Scala code to Kotlin. Everything seems to go pretty well but the compiler gives me this error and I dont know how to handle it.

Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but ExQuestion was expected for this line: return makeMap(questions, add2)

I am using a generic function because I need to access members of type A when building the map and the members would be visible through the lambda function provided.

Here's the code which you can copy into the Kotlin sandbox:

```
data class ExQuestion(val area: String, val rId: String, val text: String, val rIdAnswer: String, val line: Long)

fun main() {
    
    fun <A> makeMap(list: List<A>, addValue: (A, MutableMap<String, A>) -> Unit): Map<String, A> {
        val map = mutableMapOf<String, A>()

        for( item in list) {
            addValue(item, map)
        }
        return map
    }

    val add2: (ExQuestion, MutableMap<String, ExQuestion>) -> Unit =
            { question: ExQuestion, map: MutableMap<String, ExQuestion> ->

                val key = question.rId
                if (map[key] == null) {
                    map[key] = question
                } else {
                    println("Id Frage mehrfach vorhanden - " + key)
                }
            }
            
            val questions = listOf(ExQuestion("Area", "Q01", "text", "A01",1))

        return makeMap(questions, add2)
}
```

Working code:

```
data class ExQuestion(val area: String, val rId: String, val text: String, val rIdAnswer: String, val line: Long)

fun main() {
    
    fun <A> makeMap(list: List<A>, addValue: (A, MutableMap<String, A>) -> Unit): Map<String, A> {
        val map = mutableMapOf<String, A>()

        for( item in list) {
            addValue(item, map)
        }
        return map
    }

    val add2: (ExQuestion, MutableMap<String, ExQuestion>) -> Unit =
            { question: ExQuestion, map: MutableMap<String, ExQuestion> ->

                val key = question.rId
                if (map[key] == null) {
                    map[key] = question
                } else {
                    println("Id Frage mehrfach vorhanden - " + key)
                }
            }
            
            val questions = listOf(ExQuestion("Area", "Q01", "text", "A01",1))

    val map = makeMap(questions, add2)
    println(map.values)
}
```

Comment: you `main()` function returns Unit, when you try to return `Map<String, A>`

Comment: thanks ! still getting the error in my "real" code, have to further look into it. I have added the working code.

Comment: What's the question? 

Comment: the questions was what is causing this error as stated in the text -> Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but ExQuestion was expected for this line: return makeMap(questions, add2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but you can convert your list of `questions` to a map keyed on `rId` by doing:

```
val map = questions.map { it.rId to it }.toMap()
println(map)
```

Result:

```
{Q01=ExQuestion(area=Area, rId=Q01, text=text, rIdAnswer=A01, line=1)}
```

---

Update in response to comments.

You can achieve that without a mutable map by doing something like this:

```
val map = questions
    .groupBy { it.rId }
    .mapValues { (key, values) ->
        if (values.size > 1) println("Id Frage mehrfach vorhanden - $key")
        values.first()
    }
```

However, I think your mutable map solution is fine and arguably clearer, so this is just for demonstration.

Comment: Daniel responded to the error already but with your one liner solution I dont need a generic function with a lamda. Practically I reinvented the map function :-) Thanks !

Comment: Because I want to flag duplicates I came up with this solution:
val map = mutableMapOf<String, ExQuestion>()
questions.forEach { question ->
                val key = question.rId
                if (map[key] == null) {
                    map[key] = question
                } else {
                    println("Id Frage mehrfach vorhanden - " + key)
                }
            }

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates, or just log them?

Comment: I log duplicates but keep the first value in the map.

Comment: OK. I added another example to the answer, but sounds like you've got it. If the problem is solved please accept the answer ✓

Comment: Seems that Kotlin is not so picky on immutables than Scala is :-)